# Firebase 'value' events aren't firing in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have a function that is mean to subscribe to `value` events on a firebase child url. It looks like

```
function getMessages(chat) {
  var ref = new Firebase(".../"+chat+"/messages");
  ref.limitToLast(10).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    ...
  });
}
```

This is called from a React component's `componentWillMount` method like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
    getMessages(this.props.chat);
}
```

The first time I call this function, everything works and it's blazing fast. But if I call it with a different `chat` parameter the callback never fires. Not even once for the first load.

As far as I can tell, by putting `console.log`'s on every other line, `componentWillMount` is firing and `getMessages` is being called.

What gives? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: Note I'm trying to implement this in React Native. I've simplified even further, and have my React component connecting to firebase directly. [Check out this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/30468/). This is working perfectly in the fiddle, but in React Native while it connects the first time, if you click *back* and go into another chat, it will never fire the `value` event.

Comment: add the code example where we can see how you call getMessages and with what chat value

Comment: @Gavriel I've added a little more detail. But it's not that complicated. Everything seems to be called correctly, the value callback just never fires. Do you know any way to better debug what's happing in Firebase under the hood. I've tried adding a cancel callback to the .on() call, but that never fires either.

Comment: That sounds strange. Can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the behavior? Feel free to drop the react parts if they're not needed to get the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've put it in a fiddle and it's working perfectly. I'm starting to think it's the fact that's I'm trying to do this in React Native that's causing the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an entirely new project, it seems to work, so the problem must be somewhere else. [Here's a gist.](https://gist.github.com/nicholasstephan/a67c57091ee01854f1ab)